# OpenVPN Slows Speeds when underlying raw speed increases

Tags: networking, openvpn, internet-speed, speedtest

We are running OpenVPN on a router to an AWS cloud server to create a tunnel. AWS has over 1Gbps bandwidth up and down. We are using OpenVPN with no encryption (cipher-none) directly from the router. We have looked at the following information:
https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=22747

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Gigabit_Networks_Linux

https://winaero.com/speed-up-openvpn-and-get-faster-speed-over-its-channel/

We have done:
sndbuf 3399999

rcvbuf 3399999

push "sndbuf 3399999 "

push "rcvbuf 3399999 "

Turned compression back on (and tried off as well)

Set tunnel MTUs (to 9000, 8192, etc)

Added no fragmenting and MSSFIX: (fragment 0 mssfix 0)

Then changed back to: tun-mtu 1400 // mssfix 1360

(Nothing really changed the results.)

Here's the thing. At first, we thought we were getting great results. We were getting 87-91Mbps on a link with raw speed of about 94Mbps. Seems good, right? But we found that we had a cable in the path that was only Cat 5 (2 pairs/4 wires instead of 4 pairs/8 wires). Once we replaced that cable, our raw speeds went up to 235Mbps which is what we should have been getting all along. However, our OpenVPN speeds then DROPPED down to less than 50Mbps. We put the 100Mbps cable back in, and we got 90Mbps through the OpenVPN. But with the Gigabit cable there (and 235Mbps raw speed), we can't even get half of that through the OpenVPN now.

Is there something else we should be looking at in our quest to get the OpenVPN speed (with no encryption) up to 200Mbps or so? It should be  at least as fast as it  was previously on the 100Mbps connection.

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: Authentication is not encryption. That's the cipher. So you're still using encryption. If you need fast speed, use a different technology (WireGuard, Nebula).

Comment: so since you have pretty much shown that this is a cabling issue, what are you link-speed and duplex settings on both ends (set them to auto)? is it possible you got a bad piece of Cat6? OpenVPN is CPU-bound as well as network bound, but it doesn't appear that your load has increased so CPU usage wouldn't bog you down more than where you were at with the older cable. do note, Cat5 (even the original version) is 8 wires and supports up to 2.5Gbps at 100MHz. Cat4 is also 8 wires, and supports up to 16Mbps at 20MHz. Cat3 was a 2-pair cable, but only supported 10BaseT.

Comment: I wonder if its a crap ethernet card generating more interrupts and waits.

Comment: What is the sizing of your EC2 instance? Increase it temporarily and test again. I’ve proven to myself many times that low end t2/t3 and even low core C type instances will not deliver reliable speeds when used as a VPN endpoint. You’ll probably need at least a compute optimized xlarge or 2xlarge to obtain those speeds.

Comment: And while it seems counter intuitive that a “faster” LAN cable would reduce VPN speeds, there are definite technical reasons for this to happen as you are creating a mismatch in speeds between device capabilities which results in buffering and lost packets and increases the chance that a poor algorithm is going to misbehave.

Comment: @Daniel B: You are correct regarding cipher vs auth. I have updated the question to state it was cipher-none and not auth-none.

Comment: @Frank Thomas: You are correct that most original Cat5 still had 4 pairs (8 wires), but some did not as companies did this to save money. That's the case here. As mentioned in the post, it only had 4 wires (2 paires) which capped it at 100Mbps. When it was capped at the 100Mbps, OpenVPN speeds were great (about 90Mbps). As for a bad Cat6 cable, no - that cable is good (since we can get 235Mbps raw speed); the question is why the speeds dropped to less than 50Mbps with a better cable that isn't throttled now. Our CPU (on both sides) is at less than 15% since we are running without a cipher.

Comment: @Davidgo: Could you explain more? Wouldn't it generate the same amount of interrupts and waits when using the 100Mbps as the GigE cable? Just for the record, we're using an Intel i210AT chip on the local router (which does Gigabit Ethernet) and I'm not sure what's in the AWS instance, but it can at least do over 1Gbps.

Comment: @Appleoddity: It's an r4.large instance which says it can do up to 10Gbps for the networking. And testing it to/from other sites produces >1Gbps.

Comment: @Appleoddity: What mismatch is there in speeds between device capabilities? Could you explain more? Both devices can do over 235Mbps. I believe that it could be due to buffering, but increased speeds should not lead to more dropped packets since if both devices were keeping up at 90Mbps originally they should be able to empty the buffers at least that quickly still. If there is some algorithm that backs off too much, that could be the case, but note this is the OpenVPN algorithm we're talking about. I guess I'm asking if it's known that the OpenVPN algorithm could have this issue then?

Comment: The network throughput of the EC2 instance is not the bottleneck. It’s the capability of the system to process the data. Likely a CPU limitation. An r4.large is very small in compute power for the throughput you’re expecting. It’s worth at least trying to increase it to a 2x large temporarily. That is the beauty of the cloud. The mismatch is in the total path from end to end. If you’re overwhelming one device or link there is no way I can tell you how it might misbehave. In one case you’re limited at the physical layer at the NIC. In another case maybe it’s the CPU like I suggested.

Comment: The instance sizing issue in this EXACT scenario is a problem I’ve seen multiple times. I can tell you beyond doubt r4.large is not big enough to achieve 100Mbps of throughput as a VPN endpoint. At least not in any scenario I’ve used. But admittedly, I have never run a VPN with no encryption. However I’ve seen the same issue simply using the EC2 endpoint as a iperf testing endpoint.

Comment: I would try a c5.2xlarge temporarily. You might be surprised.

Comment: If you are using an intel card (or the same card in both instances - this was not clear to me) then the issue is likely not the card.  I was thinking if thr performance if a cheap gigabit card vs a decent 100 megabit card.